# Load JSON as array[array]

Tags: javascript, json

I'm running the python SimpleHTTPWebserver for my project to serve up a load of files, one of which is a valid JSON "file.json". For my javascript front end I need to read this as an array of arrays such that

```
{
  "val1": 101,
  "val2": 202
}
```

Becomes `var jsonFile = [['val1', 101], ['val2', 202]]`

Unfortunately I can't even get the file to load to a variable in it's raw state. I'm completely new to javaScript but have tried the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var mydata = JSON.parse("file.json");
</script>
</html>
```

However this throws an error:

> VM89:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at :1:6

As I'm new to javaScript I'm trying to keep things as simplistic as possible (whether that is using plain javascript or something like JQuery I don't care) but just can't understand why this isn't working. HELP!

Comment: you have to download the file over ajax first. JSON.parse will then parse the json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a request for the files on the server first to then be able to access the `json`.

If you make an `ajax` request and specify `json` you won't need to parse the data

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
    url: "path/to/json/file",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: response => {
      console.log(Object.entries(response));
    }
  })
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) you can get the desired result from an object `{key:value}` to `[[key,value]]`

```js
let x = {val1: 101,val2: 202};
console.log(Object.entries(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse` takes a json object string like `"{"foo":"bar"}"` and returns a json object, you are passing it the file name which is obviously ill-formatted. You must fetch the content of that json file and feed the content to `JSON.parse`. Assume you have added jquery, you can fetch that file using `XMLHttpRequest` which allows you to fetch resources asynchronously (aka ajax).

```
$.ajax('/url/of/your/file.json/on/the/server', {
    success: function(content) {
        var json = JSON.parse(content);
        var resultArray = Object.keys(json)
                                .map(function(key) {
                                    return [key,json[key]];
                                })
                                .reduce(function(container,nextArray) {
                                    container.push(nextArray);
                                    return container;
                                }, []);
       consle.log(resultArray); // resultArray is what you need
    }
});
```

[$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

[Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)